# 'TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(' statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, migration

I have a long (Oracle) SQL query which starts like this:

```
SELECT 0 run_id, 
0 tran_id,
0 sort_id,
' ' tran_type,
10 prod_id,
72 type_id,
1 value,  
TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(
'2016-03-18 00:00:00',
'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') 
+ rownum -1,
'YYYY.MM.DD')
```

Now I want to make an equivalent query in SQL Server but I could not figure out how to do the `TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE()))` part. A tool named SQLines gave me something like this: `TO_TIMESTAMP(ISNULL(TO_CHAR(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-03-18 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')` but it is clearly wrong. Is there any equivalent statement for it in SQL Server?

Comment: Do you actually understand why this Oracle transformation is done with multiple type conversion?

Comment: Your `to_timestamp()` expression is missing a format mask and a closing bracket. Also, `to_date('2016-03-18 00:00:00','YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')` can be written more simply as `date '2016-03-18'`. But then if you want to convert a `date` to a `timestamp`, just cast it. e.g. `cast(date '2016-03-18' + rownum - 1 as timestamp)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic is:

```
SELECT . . . 
       DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1,
               '2016-03-18'
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood the code is doing, this might be an equivalent. It truncates the time and add days as rownum-1.

```
--This is to create sample rows
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(rownum) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
--This is the actual formula
SELECT CONVERT( datetime2, DATEADD( DD, DATEDIFF( DD, 0,  '2016-03-18 00:00:00') + rownum - 1, 0))
FROM cteTally;
```